# How can I reduce memory consumption of lists I no longer need?

Tags: java

I've searched for this but can't seem to find a straight answer for this.

Basically I have some code that creates a copy of an array(using `Arrays.copyOf` to create `int[]`), and it does some work and either outputs the results or sends the `Arrays.copyOf` to a queue for further processing.

If I change the copyof my results are no longer correct so I think I need it but I'm wondering if there's something I can do after its done because, as per my memory profiling, its taking up all my memory and garbage collecting helps but it just builds up again.  I'm really not sure if this will help but I wanted to test to see if my program functions as it did with a smaller memory footprint if I somehow delete the `int[]` after submitting it to a queue.

I'm new to Java so if this logic is totally flawed, is there another way to achieve the same result? Bottom line is I'm creating a new array its being used a bit but lingers around when no longer needed(it takes 15G of my max memory, then I believe garbage collector comes in and reduces it but it shots back to max within a few seconds again). Maybe can I set the variable to null or something once I'm sure its not needed(the objects I'm copying are quite large)?

Here's some code just to show what I mean(its kind of crappy but hopefully it lets you understand how its setup in the code, all this is within a multithreaded callable):

```
 while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                int[] data_list = Arrays.copyOf(current.list, current.list.length);

                    if (things work) {
                        Sysout("print results");
                    } else if (current.k > 0) {
                        queue.add(new Queue(data_list)); 

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the thing to do here is "trust that the garbage collector knows what it's doing."  The JVM is very good at figuring out when objects aren't needed any more, especially e.g. if it can prove that an object doesn't "escape" the method where it was created.

Java doesn't even provide a way to delete the memory being used by an object, except eliminating all references to it -- which is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I understand that but I'm just thinking if I know the object is not going to be used anymore can I do something so my cpu can focus on the program and not have to trigger garbage collecting too early. In the current form I'm quickly running out of memory because these objects are waiting to be garbaged collected.

Comment: The GC is "smart and mysterious," but the objects might not even wait for garbage collection, if the JIT discovers that they won't leave the method under certain conditions.  In any event, there is absolutely nothing you can do to make the objects go away faster.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't care that your memory is abused by obsolete objects. When your program needs a chunk of that memory - GC will take care to free it.

Comment: okay, if I cannot remove it, can I set it to zero? or something so it takes less memory? My problem is the list I'm copying is 10,000 items and really large. Sorting multiple copies of it thats waiting to get GC is causing my program to grind to a halt. Maybe I can set it to zero until its GC?

Comment: No.  There is _nothing you can do._  Setting the reference to `null` won't actually save you any memory or speed up the GC or do anything at all really.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning about Java..why won't setting the reference to null do anything? if a large list takes 10MB and I change it to null, won't I save the memory that the list would have taken?

Comment: No.  The array will still exist until the GC decides to collect it, it just won't be referenced anywhere.  (And that's why just "not doing anything" with the array will get it GC'd just as quickly.)  If you're familiar with C or its variants, then what you'd be doing is setting a _pointer_ to `NULL`, not freeing the actual memory.

Comment: That said, what leads you to the conclusion that GC is the bottleneck?  It's astronomically more likely that either some other part of your program is problematic, or that an algorithmic improvement elsewhere would be more useful.  (That, and 10000 elements isn't much at all, unless the elements are really large objects.)

Comment: I was profiling my code and netbeans said that Arrays.copyOf was using most of my memory. I only use Arrays.copyOf once(but its in a recursion type area, code example above), my program works at first or as long as my data is small but once I max my memory the program just slows down to a halt.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` would be allocating lots of memory, but most of that memory would be getting freed almost as fast as it's allocated.  In any event, there are _no alternatives._  There is nothing else you can do to speed up GC.  Either find some way to rewrite your code to use less memory in the first place, or accept your code as it is.

Comment: I figured I had two choices, get my existing program to use less memory or rewrite.  This question was my attempt at trying to avoid the rewrite. Thanks for your help though.  I learned I can't foil the GC :-)